# Control character encode after using jquery autocomplete

Tags: json, encoding, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI autocomplete for three different form suggestions. Everything is working good, the only issue is that titles suggested aren't utf-8 (I think):

Instead of "Bla bla - Bla"
I have "Bla bla &#8211 Bla"

This is my js:

```
$('.ricerca-mirata input').focus(function() {
        var postType = $(this).data('tipo');
        var url = aela.ajax_url + "?action=my_search&post_type=" + postType;
        $( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: url,
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 3
        }); 
    });
```

And my php:

```
function my_search() {
    $term = strtolower( $_GET['term'] );
    $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
    $suggestions = array();

    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        's' => $term,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_status' => 'publish'

        ) );

    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $suggestion = array();
        $suggestion['label'] = get_the_title();
        $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();

        $suggestions[] = $suggestion;
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    $response = json_encode( $suggestions );

    echo $response;
    exit();
```

}

Have you got any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the filter [`wptexturize`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize), which is what's causing your encoding issue:

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    // Your code
}
```